# Angular Service Worker datagroup not working

Tags: angular, api, rest, timeout, service-worker

Hello can anyone help me with this service worker data group not working.
There is delay of 6 minutes in my backend api. Everything works fine when service worker is not used(ctrl+shift+R) but when service worker is used it time out in 5.2min.

[Image showing service worker timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIpVa.png)

ngsw config I have used are

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [{
    "name": "app",
    "installMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/favicon.ico",
        "/*.bundle.css",
        "/*.bundle.js",
        "/*.chunk.js"
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "name": "assets",
    "installMode": "lazy",
    "updateMode": "prefetch",
    "resources": {
      "files": [
        "/assets/**"
      ]
    }
  }],
      "dataGroups": [
        {
          "name": "api-freshness",
          "urls": [
            "",
            "/**", 
            "**//localhost:8282//**",
            "**/",
            "**/api/**",
            "**/**/**",
            "/api"

          ],
          "cacheConfig": {
            "strategy": "freshness",
            "maxSize": 5,
            "maxAge": "1d",
            "timeout": "30m",
            "version": "2"
            
          }
        }
    ]
}
```